# Impala 2.2 avro select * query not working

Tags: hadoop, avro, cloudera-cdh, amazon-emr, impala

I created external table name "operation_details" in Impala 2.2 in Amazon EMR 3.10 which reads avro schema stored at HDFS & avro files in HDFS....I am able to run all the queries on that table which are showing correct records when I run select  from operation_details  the console shows :: **WARNINGS: Unresolvable column types (column 2): declared type = DOUBLE, Avro type = string
Unresolvable column types (column 2): declared type = DOUBLE, Avro type = string
Unknown disk id.  This will negatively affect performance. Check your hdfs settings to enable block location metadata.
Fetched 0 row(s) in 0.61s**  .... I am able to access other queries like "select count(*) from operation_details" but I am not able to access **"select *" operation**...Also I am able to access the same query in Hive but not in Impala.....how can I access the select *  from tablename query ???

Answer (score 2):

The types "double" and "string" are unmatched.
Unlike Hive, Impala does not implicitly cast between string and numeric or Boolean types. Always use CAST() for these conversions.

Reference:  http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/archive/impala/2-x/2-1-x/topics/impala_langref_unsupported.html